# How can i see grafana in Windows web browser

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a **VMware Workstation pro v. 15.5.0**, in it i installed **Ubuntu 19.10, gnome 3.34.2 64bit**
And in ubuntu installed **influxDb v.1.7.10 with grafana**

Host where the vmware is:**Windows 10.0.14393 64-bit.**
I change the telegraf config in my vm, in : `etc/telegraf/telegraf.conf` in the line `service_address ="tcp://localhost:3000"` change localhost by my ip:**192.168.128.128**
After that restart the service with
`systemctl restart telegraf`
In vmware i can see grafana and data in my db.
prprIoblem: I tried to see in my host, Windows, in the web browser chrome grafana, but all the time saids that i do not have Internet conection. I put the ip:port in local pages in chrome configuration in proxy settings. I reboot VMware, my computer, see in other browser(ie, firefox) and put the same message.**it is no Internet conection**
Thanks in advance. Please, edit my question because i am in my movil and i cannot give it code structure.

Answer (score 0):

After an intense search in google i stop with a blog to install grafana, and ,in its content put that we have to **add port 3000**(grafana default) to **firewall entry rules**. This is something that is not in all articles about grafana install.

I hope this is helpful.